# Laravel model without db

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I have model Meal which can contain model Ingredient and Ingredient has a lot of properties...

I have all ingredient in DB and also some meals....

But I want to create new meal but without storing it in DB.

so something like:

```
$meal = new Meal;
$meal->ingredients()->attach(5);
```

where 5 is id of ingredient in DB.

However this will fail because $meal is not stored in DB yet and attach() function trying to create a new record in meal_ingredient table....

So is there any way how to create "offline" model and connect it with "online" data?

Thanks

Comment: But if $meal is not in the DB - then what is even the point of 'linking' it? $meal is not stored anywhere...?

Comment: meal has belongsToMany(Ingredient) so I would guess that this is what it is linking

Comment: Use `Doctrine` then, `Eloquent` can't do that, it needs both models saved before linking them.

Comment: @DusanPlavak - but my question is "why" are you trying to link them if you are not actually saving $meal? What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: I have one function which operates on model Meal, on my website I have some js which sent data via ajax and do some test on it. If user will decide later this data can be saved to the DB...

Comment: @deczo what if I have whole app based on eloquent :D?

Comment: @DusanPlavak then describe what you need it for. You can 'attach' it to the collection of related ingredients, but it makes the whole error prone.

Answer (score 11):

### Your Question:

> So is there any way how to create "offline" model and connect it with
>   "online" data?

---

### Our Take:

- Yes, you can use a sort of Laravel **Model without a Database** (offline as you phrase it). Please refer to [jenssegers/laravel-model](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-model). Basically it's a class implementing `ArrayAccess`, `ArrayableInterface`, `JsonableInterface` with some states and behaviours as needed.
- Yes, there should be a way to connect "Online" `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` with your "offline" Model: `POO` and `Design Pattern` are there to the rescue. Get your hands dirty, don't hesitate to delve into the source code!

We suggest you to roll your own "Offline" Model based on the source code of `jenssegers/laravel-model` and extend "Online" `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` (Decorator pattern or whatever!?) to make it have knowledge of the former. The plumbing is left to you, no spoon fed code so far ;-)

---

### Notes:

You may likely have to define some custom dependent (helper) classes of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` such as `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany` and so on.

FIY, you can also find a relevant sample of extending `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` here   [jarektkaczyk/Eloquent-triple-pivot](https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/Eloquent-triple-pivot) using latest PHP features.

Happy coding.

Comment: DaVe's response makes sense, as that's how new records are created from form input: you create a new instance and work with it until you save it to the database.

Comment: @dspitzle I disagree, as what you're stating depends on how you usually create objects. We tend to make all attributes `$fillable` (empty `$guarded`-array), and use `Model::create([...$attributes])` to create model instances. We hardly use the `new Model()` syntax.

Comment: Is this solution still relevant as of Laravel 8.x?

Answer (score 10):

You should treat the object like a collection to work "offline".
And remember to build the objects it they doesn't exist.

```
$ingredient = new Ingredient;
$ingredient->id = 5;

$meal = new Meal;
$meal->ingredients->add($ingredient);
```

So neither the Meal nor the Ingredient number 5 has to exists in DB.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes we want to use `Eloquent`, but without dealing a *real* database.

```php
class Currency extends Model
{
    use \Sushi\Sushi;

    protected $rows = [
        [
            'code' => 'usd',
            'title' => 'United states Dollar',
        ],
        [
            'code' => 'eur',
            'title' => 'Euro',
        ],
    ];
}
```

#### For that try:

https://github.com/calebporzio/sushi

Comment: This is helpful for static data like enumerations, but doesn't help for dynamic data.

Comment: @JayBienvenu You can use for dynamic data, just declare an empty `$rows = []`, after that you can assign any value and implement accessors or mutators from Laravel Eloquent and other features like so `$model = new Model(['name' => 'Joe'])`

Answer (score 0):

Remove extends Model at class

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;


class Person
{
   public $name;
   public $id;
   //...

}
```